# How can i put multiple touch like facebook title in UILabel/UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uilabel

I want to make UILabel like facebook's title.
Thing I want to do is multiple touch in UILabel or UITextView. What should I use?
How can I make like this http://tool.keepitreal.jp/screen.png ?
In this case, each names go to different pages if you touch.

```
    NSString* parts = @"this is test. you know?";

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"test" options:0 error:&error];
    if (error == nil) {
        NSArray *res = [regexp matchesInString:parts.string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, parts.length)];
        for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in res) {
            // change color
            [parts addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                            value:[UIColor redColor]
                          range:[match rangeAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use [NSMutableAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I tried NSMutableAttributedString. I can change font weight, but how can I set events on each names.

Comment: @naofide: show what you have tried? have you use `addAttribute` property.?

Comment: @Viruss mca: I changed top's one. I could change my font color. how can I set tap gesture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set tap gesture on UITextView and in the event-handler method:

```
CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:theTextView];
UITextPosition *tapPos = [self.textViewBelowPopup closestPositionToPoint:location];
UITextRange *wr = [self.textViewBelowPopup.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:tapPos withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionRight];
NSString *word = [self.textViewBelowPopup textInRange:wr];
```

You got the word compare it and show it on appropriate screen/page.

Comment: thanks. I tried this n I got word. but, I got lots of words. I want to get the word in more short range. can I?

Comment: sorry, I could do this by withGranularity:UITextGranularityWord. I used UITextGranularitySentence. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Naohide,

Its not possible to assign two tap gesture at different position on one control. Either you use two controls where one is normal text and other is attributed text and then assign the tap gesture.

Have a blessed day ahead